# After using len() function to the Path, the Python snippets stops executing the for loop

Tags: pathlib

The snippets does not execute the for loop after the file_counts = len(list(images)). If I drop this line, the loop is working fine. I wonder what happened. Is there anyone who can help me to explain and fix it?

```
    from pathlib import Path

    print(Path.cwd())

    path = Path.cwd()
    images = path.glob('*.jpg')
    file_counts = len(list(images))

    for image in images:
        print(f" file is {images} ")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Fix**:

Instead of converting `glob` result to `list` while computing the `len`. You should store the result as the list itself and then compute the length.

```
images = list(path.glob('*.jpg'))
file_counts = len(images)
```

**Details**:

Since, [path.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) doesn't return, but [yields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) all matching file,

```
images = path.glob('*.jpg')
```

The `images` variable you have created is not a typical container(list) which you can iterate, again and again, it is instead a [generator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generators-in-python/)

Even though generators behave like an iterator, they are exhausted after a single-use. i.e. you cannot iterate them more than once.

So when you do `list(images)` your images generator is used up for converting it into the list.
Which then you are using to get the length.

```
file_counts = len(list(images))
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. It worked. I thought that the result from the path.glob('.jpg') can be stored in the variable and then list it. It is not working that way. Logically it makes sense. For the for-loop, I just add the line for the demonstration. I knew it is the generator. Thank you again for your kind help.

Comment: can you post stack trace of the error you are getting?